# What is the A-Normal Form?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-development

I was reading about various intermediate forms but I cant get information about A-normal forms besides the wiki-like entries. Does anyone here know about this or has good resources about it?

Answer (score 8):

See [Administrative normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_normal_form).

> In computer science, administrative
> normal form (abbreviated ANF) is a
> canonical form of programs, which was
> introduced by Flanagan et al 1993 to
> serve as an intermediate
> representation in functional compilers
> to make subsequent transformations to
> machine code more direct.

> In ANF, all arguments to a function
> must be trivial. That is, evaluation
> of each argument must halt
> immediately.

> ### Grammar
>
> The following BNF grammar describes
> the pure λ-calculus modified to
> support the constraints of ANF:
>
> ```
> EXP ::= VAL 
>       | let VAR = VAL in EXP
>       | let VAR = VAL VAL in EXP
>
> VAL ::= VAR
>       | λ VAR . EXP
> ```
>
> Variants of ANF used in compilers or
> in research often allow constants,
> records, tuples, multiargument
> functions, primitive operations and
> conditional expressions as well.

Flanagan, Cormac; Sabry, Amr; Duba, Bruce F.;Felleisen, Matthias. ["The Essence of Compiling with Continuations"](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/flanagan-essence.html) likely is the definitive source.

Also found some notes on [cs252r : Advanced Functional Programming](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Egovereau/cs252r/).

Answer (score 4):

In essence, a lambda term in administrative normal form can be read as a procedure for evaluating itself, since all arguments to applications must already be in 'evaluated' and thus the order in which arguments should be evaluated must necessarily be made explicit.

There's an interesting overview in [this independently interesting paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/tacc-hs09.pdf) on a strict intermediate language for compiling lazy functional languages. Section 3.1 et seq, and especially figure 7 which gives a small-step operational semantics for a strict language in administrative normal form.

Comment: the link you've shared is broken, could you share the title or doi of the paper? thanks

Comment: Sorry. It's Types Are Calling Conventions, by Bolingbroke and Peyton Jones.